# Angular 2 - Storing and Getting Objects array from localStorage

Tags: angular, angular-local-storage

I'd like to store an array of objects in **localStorage**.

This is snippet of my code storing the array of objects at component stage.

```ts
this._authenticationService.getProfilByLogin(this.form.value.j_username)
  .subscribe(result => {
     console.log('inside getting profils');
     console.log(result.json().ecomServices);
     localStorage.setItem('services_assigned', result.json().ecomServices);
  }, error => {
```

This is the code trying to get it back in another component.

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
  import {EcomService} from "../../model/EcomService";

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-sidebar-nav',
    templateUrl: './sidebar-nav.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sidebar-nav.component.css']
  })
  export class SidebarNavComponent implements OnInit {


    public ecomServices: EcomService[] = [];

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.ecomServices = localStorage.getItem('services_assigned');
    }
  }
```

This is my **model** class

```ts
export class EcomService {

  public eseCode: number;
  public eseLabel: string;

}
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: my code can't hold and array of objects in localStorage and gets it back from another component.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While storing in local storage store something like this

`localStorage.setItem('services_assigned', JSON.stringify(this.ecomServices));`

While getting back do something like this.

`this.ecomServices = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('services_assigned'));`

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the answer from Prathmesh is that if the key 'services_assigned' doesn't exist in localStorage you will get an error.

So the best way to get the array is:

`this.ecomServices = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('services_assigned') || '[]');`

Note how that provides a default (empty array) if getItem returns null because we've never stored our services there.

To store the array:

`localStorage.setItem('services_assigned', JSON.stringify(this.ecomServices));`

Comment: If storage doesn't have the value, it will throw error. Good that we have provided an empty array if getItem returns null. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In my project i have just simply create storage service to work with localStorage:

```
@Injectable()
export class CacheService {

    constructor() {}

    public get(key) {
        const data = localStorage.getItem(key);
        return !_.isEmpty(data) ? _.cloneDeep(JSON.parse(data)) : [];
    }

    public set(data, key) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    public reset() {
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}
```